# Android - error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'

Tags: android, g++, native, gnu-make

Ok, I give up...

I've been trying to compile android's 4.x (x>=1) webkit to bypass the 4.0 bugs.
After a few compilations, of the libwebcore with correct bindings and different namespace, and android.webkit with different namespace and some code fixes to match 4.0 - it compiles, and works, on Android 4.3.

Additional problems came in when trying to run it on 4.0-4.2 - where I found out the libicuuc is incompatible between versions, as versioning occurs in the function names. So the solution is theoretically simple - compile libicuuc *statically* into the libwebcore, by adding `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libicuuc` to the Android.mk

This is where hell began: I get errors like `error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'` and `error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast'`.

I tried adding `LOCAL_RTTI_FLAG := -frtti` but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks!